# Change the hadoop.tmp.dir

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to to change the hadoop.temp.dir on the core-site.xml (on windows)

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>temp/teste</value>
  </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

However whenever I change it I get the following error when doing a map reduce
job

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1396600669739_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1396600669739_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1396600669739_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode:-1000 due to: File file:/C:/hadoop/sbin/temp/teste/nm-local-dir/usercache/johndoe/appcache/application_1396600669739_0001/temp/teste/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1396600669739_0001_02_000001.tokens does not exist
```

I am not entirely sure if I did something wrong or I have to change anything else

Comment: Can you look through task tracker and job tracker logs to see if there is more information about the error?

Meanwhile, the first thing I'd check would be that this folder `temp/teste` exists and has permissions allowing user johndoe to write into it.